# access database not updating after editing fields

Tags: c#, database, oledb

I am developing a program for a Computer Store using c# with VS2010 and Database Provider = OleDB.
I need a form for updating the existing Products information in the stock. So I have a DataGridView to show the products Table (Edit property = on)

**My code for updating a row :**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow UpdateRow = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
        if (UpdateRow.Selected == true)
        {
            try
            {
                com.CommandText = "UPDATE Products SET ProductName=@pname,Model=@model WHERE ProductID= " + UpdateRow.Cells[0].Value + "";
                com.Connection = con;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", UpdateRow.Cells[1].Value);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", UpdateRow.Cells[2].Value);
                int count = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); 
            }
        }    
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

That code works and it updates the access database file but it's only for one row (the selected row)

Now i want to update every edit the user have done in the `DataGridView`

So all i have to do is to **delete** the line `if (UpdateRow.Selected == true)` and that way , the loop will go for every row and update the info .

I debugged the program and it didn't crash but the Access database **didn't update** anything! I wonder why...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods to accomplish this:

1. Follow the dataset and datatable route, assign the datatable to the grid and then use the getchanges() method to retrieve the rows which have changed and then update the selected rows into the database
2. Use the following following function to capture the rowindex property of the changed row

   ```
    private void dataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
         {
       // use  e.rowindex to get the row being modified and keep that in some list and 

        //after update button is pressed get the rows and update accordingly
      //
          }
   ```